# How can we interpret this residuals vs predictor plot

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, linear

I am running an analysis on data and have found a viable model, however I am testing to see whether interaction terms between predictors should be included. What conclusions can be drawn from the plot?  On first impression it seems that the plot is well behaved, however, the left seems to cluster. [image]

Comment: How is the numerical variable `blast furnace` measured?  Would it perhaps be a indicator (binary) variable that equals $0$ for many of the observations?

Comment: yes that is the case. the dataset falls has many zeros at the beginning of the dataset.

Comment: Isn't the appearance of a cluster at zero inevitable, then?  Or do you mean something else by "seems to cluster"?